# Downgrading to AngularJS 1.2.28 from 1.3.x Error: $injector:modulerr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I'm having to downgrade AngularJS from 1.3 to 1.2.28 so that I can support IE8 (my client decided they needed to support it after we got started).  The first step I took was to change all the references to AngularJS to 1.2.28 as such:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular-loader.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my setup in my app.module.js :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('mn', [
            'ngRoute',
            'angularSpinner',
            'angular-cache',
            'ngSanitize',
            'ui.bootstrap',
            'mn.catalog',
            'mn.common',            
        ])
    .run(CacheSetup);

    CacheSetup.$inject = ['CacheFactory'];

    /** @ngInject */
    function CacheSetup(CacheFactory) {
        CacheFactory.createCache('profileCache', {
            maxAge: 30 * 60 * 1000, //30 min
            deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive',
            storageMode: 'sessionStorage',
            storagePrefix: 'si-cache.caches.'
        });

        CacheFactory.createCache('ransCache', {
            maxAge: 30 * 60 * 1000, //30 min
            deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive',
            storageMode: 'sessionStorage',
            storagePrefix: 'si-cache.caches.'
        });
    }
})();
```

Here is my app.routes.js file:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('mn')
        .config(config);

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

    /** @ngInject */
    function config($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when("/AccountSettings", {
                templateUrl: "/angularRoot/modules/accountSettings/login.html",
                controller: 'AccountSettingsController as vm',
                caseInsensitiveMatch: true
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/welcome'
            });
    }
})();
```

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Page Title</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular-loader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="angularRoot/externalReference/spin.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angularRoot/externalReference/vendor/jquery.main.js"></script>
    <script src="angularRoot/externalReference/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angularRoot/externalReference/linq.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angularRoot/externalReference/respond.min.js"></script>

    <script src="angularRoot/core/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="angularRoot/core/app.routes.js"></script>

    <script src="angularRoot/modules/accountActivity/accountActivity.module.js"></script>
    <script  src="angularRoot/modules/accountActivity/accountActivity.controller.js">   </script>

    <link href="css/3rdParty/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/vendorStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body ng-app='mn' ng-strict-di>

    <div id="wrapper" ng-view>
    </div>

    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
         <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to    improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting this error in Google Chrome and the page is completely blank:

```
Failed to instantiate module mn due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr]       http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/modulerr?p0=...)
at Error (native)
at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular.min.js:6:450
at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular.min.js:34:97
at r (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular.min.js:7:290)
at e (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular.min.js:33:207)
at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular.min.js:33:284
at r (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular.min.js:7:290)
at e (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular.min.js:33:207)
at ec (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular.min.js:36:309)
at c (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular.min.js:18:170
```

Comment: Don't use minified version of Angular for development. Then you will get more meaningful error messages.

Comment: You can't declare controllers with the `function MyCtrl` syntax.

Comment: What is the full error link in the stack trace. It'll let us dig in for you.

Comment: @alisabzevari please don't give wrong info to users .. you need to look at this http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.in/2013/11/ControllerAsSyntaxInAngularJs1.2.html

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you missed to load `ui.bootstrap` related files, you only loaded `bootstrap.js`

As you are using Angular 1.X you need to use 0.12.0 is the last version of this library that supports AngularJS 1.2.x.

Visit here [**Angular ui bootstrap**](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and look for Getting Started Module.

Answer (score 0):

Please dont use this directive 'ng-strict-di'. It is introduced in angular 1.3 .Here is the attached link for reference

http://bartwullems.blogspot.in/2014/10/angularjs-13-ng-strict-di-directive.html

Answer (score 0):

Per @Pavel Horal's advice, I switched to non minimized angular and got the full error and it actually showed that I was missing a few modules, one of them being Angular UI Bootstrap as pankajparkar noted.

There are still other issues with downgrading that I'm fighting through, but switching to non-minimized version has really helped find them all.